# JavaDoc 18 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) jdk-18.0.1.1
Exporting JavaDoc displays following error:

```
javadoc: error - error: invalid source release: 18
1 error
```

But using Maven the JavaDoc is processed correctly with no errors.

Any suggestions for how to correct the Eclipse problem would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Eclipse 2022-03 doesn't support Java 18 unless you install a patch. Eclipse 2022-06 out on the 15th June does support Java 18.

Comment: I have that installed and am using some of the new features, so I know I can compile Jave 18. I just can't run JavaDoc from Eclipse.

Comment: Is it being run from a Java 18 JDK?

Comment: from the eclipse.ini
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

Comment: I mean the `javadoc` executable, not Eclipse.

Comment: Make sure that in _Project > Generate Javadoc..._ the field _Javadoc command_ refers to the Javadoc executable of a Java 18 JDK.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Once I changed the configure JavaDoc in the export it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in the dialog that is shown for *Project > Generate Javadoc...*, the field ***Javadoc command* refers to** the Javadoc executable of a **Java 18** JDK.